# Composite plot in PGFPlot

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to get `pgfplots` to do produce a plot like the following:

[image]

i.e. a scatterplot with a second scatterplot below the x-axis.

I am having a hard time figuring out how this kind of plot is called (the PGF gallery has does not seem to feature this particular example) and any help regarding the technical name of this kind of diagram and how to produce it using `pgfplots` would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing what you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: You should be able to do this with a subplot and by removing the inter-plot distance. But I agree wih @Jubobs that you should provide a minimal working example of what you've tried up to now, then we might be able to help you better...

Comment: I guess Habi means the `groupplots` library, with `vertical sep` set to zero. See the manual (just search for 'groupplots' to find it).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`MWE` with `Asymptote` (no `pgfplots`, sorry).
The `inclusive fit` function is faked with approximation curve,
but the `4-th order polynomial` trend curve 
is calculated automatically.

```
% cplot.tex :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{asydef}
struct Trend{
  real x[], y[];
  real xnorm[], ynorm[];
  int n;
  int degree;
  real xmin,xmax;
  real ymin,ymax;
  real xrange,yrange;
  string spoly;
  real[][] A;
  real[] b;
  real[] TrendCoeffs;
  real f(real x){
    real v=0;
    real t=(x-xmin)/xrange;
    for(int i=0;i<=degree;++i){
      v=v*t+TrendCoeffs[degree-i];
    }
    return v*yrange+ymin;
  } 

  void normalize(){
    xmin=min(x); xmax=max(x);
    ymin=min(y); ymax=max(y);
    xrange=xmax-xmin; yrange=ymax-ymin; 
    xnorm=map(new real(real i){return (x[(int)i]-xmin)/xrange;},sequence(n));
    ynorm=map(new real(real i){return (y[(int)i]-ymin)/yrange;},sequence(n));
  }

  void calcTrendCoeffs(){
    A=array(degree+1,array(degree+1,0.0));
    b=array(degree+1,0);
    A[0][0]=n;
    for(int i=1;i<=degree;++i){
      A[0][i]=sum(xnorm^i);
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=degree;++i){
      A[i][degree]=sum(xnorm^(i+degree));
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=degree;++i){
      for(int j=0;j<degree;++j){
        A[i][j]=A[i-1][j+1];
      }
    }

    b[0]=sum(ynorm);
    for(int i=1;i<=degree;++i){
      b[i]=sum(ynorm*xnorm^i);
    }
    TrendCoeffs=solve(A,b);
  };

  void operator init(real[] x,real[] y, int degree=2){
    this.x=copy(x);
    this.y=copy(y);
    this.degree=degree;
    this.n=x.length;
    assert(degree>1 && degree<7 && n>degree && y.length==n);
    normalize();
    calcTrendCoeffs();
  }
}
\end{asydef}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
import graph;

pen trendPen=red+1.6bp+linetype(new real[]{2,2})+squarecap;
pen inclFitPen=deepblue+1.7bp+opacity(0.5);
pen markPen=brown;

defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));

real[] yTop={
1848,1817,1771,1618,1733,1641,1549,1587,1480,1511,1442,1411,1342,1357,1350,1258,
1273,1188,1165,1089,1073,1142,1112,1066,1020,1081,1066,1020,943,966,905,874,
805,882,797,790,767,721,698,698,721,667,652,613,675,606,590,552,
567,567,575,544,498,483,521,475,498,514,468,468,
};

real[] x=map(new real(real k){return 100.5+k;},sequence(yTop.length));

unitsize(25mm,0.02mm);

real xmin=100;
real xmax=160;
real ymin=0;
real ymax=2400;

frame mark; filldraw(mark,scale(2bp)*unitcircle,white,markPen+0.4bp);

draw(graph(x,yTop),nullpen,marker(mark),legend="\textsf{Data 2011 and 2012}");

Trend trend4=Trend(x,yTop,degree=4);
guide gTrend=graph(trend4.f,xmin,xmax);
guide gInclFit=
 subpath(gTrend,0,20*2)
 ..controls (x[26],yTop[26]+60) and (x[28],yTop[28]+40)
 ..subpath(gTrend,24*2,size(gTrend));

draw(gInclFit,inclFitPen
,legend="\textsf{Sig + Bkg inclusive fit ($\mathsf{m_{H} = 126.5}$ GeV)}");

draw(gTrend,trendPen,legend="\textsf{4-th order polynomial}");

string noTickLabels(real x){return "";};

xaxis(xmin,xmax,Ticks(ticklabel=noTickLabels,Step=10,step=2));
xaxis(XEquals(ymax),xmin,xmax,RightTicks(ticklabel=noTickLabels,Step=10,step=2));
yaxis(YEquals(xmin),ymin,ymax,RightTicks(Label(LeftSide),Step=200,step=50,beginlabel=false));
yaxis(YEquals(xmax),ymin,ymax,LeftTicks(ticklabel=noTickLabels,Step=200,step=50));

real y2min=-160;
real y2max=160;

real[] yBot;

for(int i=0;i<yTop.length;++i){
  yBot.push(yTop[i]-trend4.f(x[i]));
}

int yBotTicks=16;

real ystep=50;
real yStep=250;

xaxis(XEquals(ymin-yBotTicks*ystep),xmin,xmax
  ,LeftTicks(Label(RightSide),Step=10,step=2));

yaxis(YEquals(xmin),ymin-yBotTicks*ystep,ymin);
yaxis(YEquals(xmax),ymin-yBotTicks*ystep,ymin
  ,LeftTicks(ticklabel=noTickLabels,Step=yStep,step=ystep));

pair v;
for(int i=0;i<yBotTicks;++i){
  v=(xmin,ymin-i*ystep);
  ytick(v,size=ticksize);
}

ytick("$100$",(xmin,ymin-3*ystep),size=Ticksize);
ytick("$0$",(xmin,ymin-8*ystep),size=Ticksize);
ytick("$-100$",(xmin,ymin-13*ystep),size=Ticksize);

transform topXY(){
  transform t=shift(0,-8*ystep)*scale(1,50/20);
  return t;
}

draw(topXY()*graph(x,yBot),nullpen,marker(mark));

guide gTrendBot=topXY()*((xmin,0)--(xmax,0));

draw(gTrendBot,trendPen);

guide gInclFitBot=topXY()*((xmin,0)--(x[23],0))
 ..controls topXY()*(x[26],yBot[26]+60) and topXY()*(x[30],yBot[28]+40)
 ..topXY()*((x[30],0)--(x[x.length-1],0));

draw(gInclFitBot,inclFitPen);

size(300,300,(xmin,ymin-13*ystep),(xmax,ymax));

label(rotate(90)*"\textsf{Events / Gev}",(93,ymax),SW);
label(rotate(90)*"\textsf{Data - Bkg}",(93,0),SW);
label("\textsf{\textbf{\textit{ATLAS}}} \textsf{Preliminary}",(105,200),E);
label("$\mathsf{\sqrt{s}=7\,\mathsf{TeV} \displaystyle\int\! L\,dt = 4.8\,fb^{-1}}$",(130,1510),E);
label("$\mathsf{\sqrt{s}=8\,\mathsf{TeV} \displaystyle\int\! L\,dt = 5.9\,fb^{-1}}$",(130,1180),E);
label("\textsf{Selected diphoton sample}",point(N),4S);

add(legend(invisible),point((N+1.4E)),W);

shipout(bbox(Fill(paleyellow)));
\end{asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
%    
% Process:
%
% pdflatex cplot.tex
% asy cplot-*.asy   
% pdflatex cplot.tex
```